# Javascript window location on woocommerce submit button

Tags: javascript, html, woocommerce

I need to add some custom parameters to my thank you page in woocommerce. In a normal occasion i would usually just add the following code to my submit button.

```
onclick="window.location.href = 'https://mywebsite.com/thank-you?companyName=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('handelsnaam').value) + '&CPLastname=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('achternaam').value) + '&EXTRAOPMERKING=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('opmerking').value)
```

How can I achieve the same results in woocommerce. I would like to add these parameters to my URL in woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to the functions.php helped me achieve what I was looking for.

```
/// This would output 'http://blog.example.com/2009/04/16/?hello=world'
echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'hello', 'world', 'http://blog.example.com/2009/04/16/' ) );
```